# Do I always use the thickest possible line in grass trimmer?

Tags: grass, tools

Just as an example, Stihl FS130 grass trimmer can be equipped with Autocut 25-2 cutting head that can hold either 2.4 mm or 2.7 mm cutting line - so within the same trimmer and the same head I can choose which line to use. It looks like the thicker line is stronger so won't wear out that fast and so I should prefer thicker line whenever possible.

Why would I not use the thickest cutting line possible?

Answer (score 2):

> Why would I not use the thickest cutting line possible?

Because thinner line cuts thinner things like grass better.  I am toying with the idea of buying a 2nd trimmer or 2nd trimmer head for the thinner line so I don't have to switch between thick and thin line on the same spool.

The thick line is suitable for thick vegetation, but the thick line doesn't cut grass very well... it just blows it down against the ground.  The thin line cuts grass, but isn't thick enough to handle the stalky vegetation.